# pgfplots bar plot: spacing inbetween bars

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

How can I increase the spacing between the bars in a bar plot from pgfplots?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    every axis plot post/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    ybar,
    x=3cm,
    ymin=-0.1,
    ymax=12,
    xtick=data,
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    bar width=15pt,
    symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
    nodes near coords,
    axis lines*=left,
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(A,2) (B,0.5) (C,10)};
\addplot coordinates {(A,20) (B,30) (C,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(A,6) (B,11) (C,7)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to increase the space between the bars (A,2), (A,20), (A,6) (and analogously with B's and C's).

And on another note: How can I deal with values that are too large to be displayed? (e.g (B,30))

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can set the spacing between the bars using the optional argument to `ybar` (the default is `2pt`).

For indicating that some of the data values exceed the axis range, you could clip the values at some level that's slightly larger than your axis limit using `restrict y to domain*=0:<value>`, making sure that you set `clip=false` so that the bars can protrude beyond the axis. You can make the original unclipped y values available for use in the `nodes near coords` by setting `visualization depends on=rawy \as \rawy`, and draw a line indicating the interruption using a `after end axis/.code` key:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    every axis plot post/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    ybar=5pt,
    bar width=12pt,
    x=3cm,
    ymin=0,
    axis on top,
    ymax=12,
    xtick=data,
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
    restrict y to domain*=0:14, % Cut values off at 14
    visualization depends on=rawy\as\rawy, % Save the unclipped values
    after end axis/.code={ % Draw line indicating break
            \draw [ultra thick, white, decoration={snake, amplitude=1pt}, decorate] (rel axis cs:0,1.05) -- (rel axis cs:1,1.05);
        },
    nodes near coords={%
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\rawy}% Print unclipped values
        },
    axis lines*=left,
    clip=false
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(A,2) (B,0.5) (C,10)};
\addplot coordinates {(A,20) (B,30) (C,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(A,6) (B,11) (C,7)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Do you know how to deal with the large bars (A,20), (B,30)? I don't want to set the ``ymax`` to a higher value, but I want convey that these bars are too high.

Comment: @MartinG: I've edited my answer to include one way of interrupting the bars. Is that what you were thinking of?

Comment: @Jake The problem with this solution is that it only works if all the data groups have values in range. If you remove your first and third `\addplot` statements, plotting just `{(A,20) (B,30) (C,1)}` then this breaks. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. In order to make it work I also had to set `ymax` to a value smaller than the `restrict y to domain`.