# Break y axis for values exceeding range

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

Related to [this question regarding values that exceed the axis range](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88896/39530) (which also provides the code for a MWE), I would like to modify the output slightly: instead of displaying the numbers above the bars, the y axis should be cut off as well (obviously, this only works if the exceeding values are in the same range which they are in my case).

Here's a picture of how I thought of it:
[image: example with cut off axis and chart]

Does pgfplots provide keys that allow such a modification of the axis?

Comment: No, PGFPlots only provides a key to allow breaking the axis at the origin (to show that the axis range doesn't include 0).

Comment: That's... unfortunate. Is there a trick to achieve the behavior anyway?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: That's a good hint, I hadn't found that question. I'm currently trying to combine it with the other link I posted.